# display the product as sold out when the value of sold_out is set to true using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to write a code to display products as out of stock which are sold out in my website, i'm using is.sold_out = true which displays the products to be out of stock, but when i go to the cart page, it say cannot read the property "sold_out" of undefined, this happens only after adding the products. i have added the product that is not yet sold.

Here is the error screenshot.

[image]

This the code I've written for sold out products.

```
<CardContent className="content">
          <Typography
            className="title"
            gutterBottom
            variant="h5"
            component="h2"
          >
            {product.name}
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
        {!!product.is.sold_out && (
          <Typography variant="h3">OutOfStock</Typography>
        )}
```

Comment: The dot(.) operator is used to refer to the property of an object. When you write product.is.sold_out, it is interpreted as trying to refer to the product object's "is" property's, "sold_out" property value. Can you post the structure of product object? Try renaming "is.sold_out" to "is_sold_out".

Answer (score 0):

You can quick fix with `optional chaining`:

```
{product?.is?.sold_out && (
  <Typography variant="h3">OutOfStock</Typography>
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `product` doesn’t have an `is` property on it, or it is there but has the value `undefined`.

You can [use optional chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69016364/19818) to avoid the error, but you may have a logic problem elsewhere you need to solve. Whatever code creates the `product` object needs to be inspected if you expect it to be creating the `is` property, because it’s not doing that now.